# ¿Como consultar rango de fechas desde cualquier formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En un formulario principal tengo este rango de fechas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber si hay manera de poder accerder a este rango de fechas en todo el sistema, para ya no repetir el codigo tantas veces, por decir en un formulario hijo acceder al rango de fechas que muestra el formulario padre, esto lo ocupo para filtrar los datos mediante este rango.
Este es el codigo que uso para hacer ese rango de fechas:

```
private DateTime[] Periodo(DateTime date)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = date.DayOfWeek;
        int diffLunes = DayOfWeek.Monday - day;
        if(diffLunes > 0)
        {
            diffLunes -= 7;
        }
        DateTime lunes = date.AddDays(diffLunes);

        int diffSabado = DayOfWeek.Saturday - day;
        if(diffSabado < 0)
        {
            diffSabado += 7;
        }
        DateTime sabado = date.AddDays(diffSabado);

        var res = new DateTime[2];
        res[0] = lunes;
        res[1] = sabado;
        return res;
    }
```

Quiero evitar repetir este codigo en cada ventana donde lo necesite.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento , si tienes código subelo por favor, Según lo que preguntas debes de usar variables globales o archivos de configuración en los cuales definas el periodo de tiempo, o almacenarlos en variables de session , no se como quieres  validar esto, si lo quieres hacer desde la vista puedes almacenarlo en localStorage o sessionStorage

Comment: @Macx se ocupa un extracto del código para entender el contexto del problema.

Comment: tengo ese codigo, pero quiero saber si hay manera de usar o pasar el resultado a otros formularios, el codigo que puse lo tengo en el formulario padre

Comment: Puedes implementar el método en una clase abstracta con el modificador de acceso protected, utilizando la herencia.

Comment: Si estas trabajando con windows forms?

Comment: si, estoy trabajando con windows forms

Comment: Pues ahí están las opciones: Utilizar la herencia en los formularios, crear una extensión para `DateTime` o implementar todas esas funcionalidades globales en una clase estática. Por ejemplo `Utilities.cs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que lo que ocupas es lo siguiente:

Ocupas crear un formulario base ("padre") que herede de la clase `Form` para obtener el comportamiento de un formulario y ahí implementar el método que quieres compartir con el resto de los formularios.
Nora: El resto de los formularios ("Hijos") deben de heredar de del formulario base ("padre").

#### Herencia

```
public class CommonForm : Form
{
    protected DateTime[] Periodo(DateTime date)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = date.DayOfWeek;
        int diffLunes = DayOfWeek.Monday - day;
        if(diffLunes > 0)
        {
            diffLunes -= 7;
        }
        DateTime lunes = date.AddDays(diffLunes);

        int diffSabado = DayOfWeek.Saturday - day;
        if(diffSabado < 0)
        {
            diffSabado += 7;
        }
        DateTime sabado = date.AddDays(diffSabado);

        var res = new DateTime[2];
        res[0] = lunes;
        res[1] = sabado;
        return res;
    }
}

public class FormA : CommonForm
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        var range = Periodo(DateTime.now());

        // More code
    }

    // Other mothods
}

public class FormB : CommonForm
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        var range = Periodo(DateTime.now());

        // More code
    }

    // Other mothods
}
```

#### Otra opción:

Crear una extensión para `DateTime` e implementar el metodo `Periodo`:

```
public static class CustomDateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime[] Periodo(this DateTime date)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = date.DayOfWeek;
        int diffLunes = DayOfWeek.Monday - day;
        if(diffLunes > 0)
        {
            diffLunes -= 7;
        }
        DateTime lunes = date.AddDays(diffLunes);

        int diffSabado = DayOfWeek.Saturday - day;
        if(diffSabado < 0)
        {
            diffSabado += 7;
        }
        DateTime sabado = date.AddDays(diffSabado);

        var res = new DateTime[2];
        res[0] = lunes;
        res[1] = sabado;
        return res;
    }
}

public class AnyFormABC : Form
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        var range = DateTime.now().Periodo();
    }
}
```

Saludos